# functions minimized at extreme value.

Tags: convex-optimization, piecewise-continuity

Given two ordered sequence $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ where $a_i \leq a_{i+1}$, and  $b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n$ where $b_i \geq b_{i+1}$ and $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

I can construct a new sequence $S$ by merging two sequence $S =  (a_1, b_1), \cdots, (a_n, b_n)$.

And the function i'm interested $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has following property: for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, both $f((x, c)) $ and $f((c, x)) $ are piece-wise linear convex.

Let $s^* = \textbf{argmin}_{s \in S} f(s)$, my question is what are the extra properties does $f$ needs to have, such that $s^* \in \{ s_1, s_n \}$ ?

Comment: if we express your problem as a linear optimization problem, we would be done - but not immediately sure how, except for a hunch that there must be a way

Comment: my goal is not to find the optimal solution but to understand when $s^* \in \{s_1, s_n\}$. And $f$ is a function related to $S$ and not having explicit form. There is a heuristic that simply check $\{ s_1, s_n \}$ for the minimum and works very well in practice, i'm interested in why that works. @gt6989b

Comment: The idea is, if we write your problem as a linear optimization problem, i.e. $\min_{x \in A} f(x)$ where $A$ is described by linear constraints (i.e. $A$ is a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$), then you can use Kantorovich's result saying that if there is an optimal solution inside $A$, there must be an equivalent one on $\partial A$, the boundary of $A$. It follows by repeated application that there must be optimum at one of the vertices of $A$...

Comment: the idea is really nice, do you have links for more resources on Kantorovich's result ? all i find is about Transportation theory @gt6989b

Comment: he describes the idea in his nobel prize biography https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/economic-sciences/1975/kantorovich/biographical/ cannot find exact result anywhere though